# When configuring a test using Artillery, how can we pause between scenarios versus flows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance-testing, regression-testing, artillery

I'd like to find out how to pause between scenarios versus flows. The advantage to this is that scenarios are labeled and those labels show up in the final report to indicate which requests were made and if they succeeded.

I've gone through the documentation found at artillery.io and even found an example of how to pause between flows: https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/engines/http with the following example

```
scenarios
- name: "Scenario Name"
  flow: 
  - post:
      url: "/url"
  - think: 5
  - post:
      url: "/url2"
```

However, the only issue with this is you are unable to label each request. Is it possible to pause between scenarios, for example:

```
scenarios
- name: "Scenario Name"
  flow: 
  - post:
      url: "/url"

- name: "Scenario Name 2"
  flow: 
  - post:
      url: "/url2"
```